# I have a list of bullets inside a jumbotron. I want the image to be next to it the exact same size as bullets?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

EDIT: I've managed to resize the image, I had to make a static number, but I more wanted the height to be determened by the length of the list. Aside from that, my new issue is making it align next to the text WITHIN the jumbotron. 
Align="right" put the image to the right, but makes it sloppy and over laps the bottom of the jumbotron border.

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="secrets">
        <h2> The Five Basics </h2>
        <ul>
            <li> number 1 </li>
            <li> number 2</li>
            <li> number 3 </li>
            <li> number 4 </li>
            <li> number 5 </li>
        </ul>
        <div class ="mindpower">
            <img src="images/mindpower.jpg"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS main.css (my css)

```
.secrets img {
    max-width:25%;
    height:atuo;
}
```

CSS bootstrap.css

```
.jumbotron {
    padding: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.jumbotron h1,
.jumbotron .h1 {
    color: inherit;
}
.jumbotron p {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 200;
}
.jumbotron > hr {
    border-top-color: #d5d5d5;
}
.container .jumbotron {
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.jumbotron .container {
    max-width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .jumbotron {
        padding-top: 48px;
        padding-bottom: 48px;
    }
    .container .jumbotron {
        padding-right: 60px;
        padding-left: 60px;
    }
    .jumbotron h1,
    .jumbotron .h1 {
        font-size: 63px;
    }
}
```

This puts a nice grey background behind the list, like a jumbotron. When I place the image, it goes below the list making the jumbotron expand and it looks really ugly. I'm trying to get it so the image goes directly beside the list, keeping the hight as big as the list gets and also keeping the preportion correct.

Answer (score 0):

See if this can fix this issue. Here I have added bootstrap column size 6 for each div, you can adjust according to yours requirement:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="col-md-6 secrets ">
        <h2> The Five Basics </h2>
        <ul>
            <li> number 1 </li>
            <li> number 2</li>
            <li> number 3 </li>
            <li> number 4 </li>
            <li> number 5 </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 mindpower">
        <img src="images/mindpower.jpg"> </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It did put the image next to my text which was great, but it totally screw up the jumbotron and the image never rezied to be the same length as the list. I'm going to try and add my css.

Comment: Adjust col-md-{value} based on yours list and image widths.

Comment: did not make a difference when I did that. It also messes with all the code I have under those div's.